# Not finding class based on requested URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

This is my .htaccess in mvc project

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is my simple class in controllers folder

```
class index {
    function __construct()
    {
        echo "this page is index";
    }
}
```

and this is my index page and i want when in controller part in url is index it prints controller part and run class. But it errors:

```
Undefined index: url
```

and

```
require(controllers/.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

My code:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$url = rtrim($url,'/');
$url = explode('/',$url);//breaks string to array
require 'controllers/'.$url[0].'.php';
$controller = new index();
print_r($url);
```

Comment: Read up about `spl_autoload_register()` and PSR4. Also, none of this is even tangentially related to MVC.

Comment: The error (actually it is only a warning) you receive indicates that the rewriting rule you posted does not get applied. Maybe you have other rules in place that get applied before?

Answer (score 0):

- Don't forget to rewrite the "base" for the redirect (`RewriteBase`).
- Remove the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l`. Does a `-l`
  option even exists?

Here is an example with a document root "Publics", in which the file "index.php" resides:

```
<Directory "[your-absolute-path-to]/Publics">
    Options FollowSymLinks

    # Uncomment if you want to only allow localhost.
    # Allow from 127.0.0.1

    # Activate rewriting engine.
    RewriteEngine On

    # Allow pin-pointing to "index.php" using RewriteRule.
    RewriteBase /

    # Rewrite url only if no physical folder name is given in url.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Rewrite url only if no physical file name is given in url.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # Take the common url and parse it through "index.php" as a query string, e.g as "url=[...]".
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # SEE: RewriteRule Flags >> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,B]
</Directory>
```